# If I have both the year and the week # (ISO-8601 week number of year) in PHP, how do I get a date?

Tags: php, date, timestamp

Eg if I have year = 2014 and week # = 22, how do I get a YYYY-mm-dd date out of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/strtotime),

```
$year = 2014; 
$week = 9; 

$date = strtotime($year."W".substr("0".$week, -2));
// e.g. strtotime("2014W09")

echo date("Y-m-d",$date);
```

Output:

```
2014-02-24
```